# Change only one cell value on select statement

Tags: sql-server

i have these db tables:

```
 Table Combo:
id int identity(1,1)
name varchar
duration int
type int

table related
sourcecombo int
destinationcombo int
finalCombo int

sales
id int identity(1,1)
username varchar
comboid int
saledate datetime
```

Now, if a combo has a duration=0, it means that the client is upgrading or downgrading its product. In the interface, I need to display the destinactioncombo value, with the condition that the sales table has one record comboid, where duration=0.But I need to display the value only at the cell that has as a primary value sourceCombo. The query I am trying to use is the following:

```
    if exists 
(select comboid 
from sales 
inner join combo on sales.comboid=combo.id
where combo.duration=0 and  username=@name)
select sales.username,saledate, 
(select destinationcombo from related
where FinalCombo = 
(select comboid
from sales where 
saledate=(select max(saledate) from 
Sales where username=@name)))
as comboid from Sales where username=@name
else select  '0'
```

where `@name` is a value taken by input from the user. The result i get until now, is the following:
[image: Results1]

The problem is, that it does capture the destinationCombo as it should, but it displays it at every single row when it has to display only at the last row.

**UPDATE 1**

So, the steps I should follow to achieve the result are like follows:

1. Check the `sales` table if it has any combo with duration=0 for
   the selected user
2. If there is a result, then take the most recent combo (with
   duration<>0 and with most recent saledate)
3. After finding that combo, than calculate from `relation` the
   destinationcombo, where FinalCombo is the combo found on step 1) and
   sourcecombo is the combo found on step 2).

Let's hope this clears the question a little more

Comment: Please add a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or script that can be used to build your schema, insert some basic test data and run your query. This will help you get an answer more quickly and accurately. At the moment, it's a little bit hard to tell what you want. Do you want the first 4 rows to have a `NULL` for `comboid` (with the `15` only present for the last row)? It's hard to understand why you'd want such a result, so maybe I am misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: @GeoffPatterson it actually is a complicated situation. I am updating  the question with the steps that I need to follow, maybe this will help.

Comment: I'd be happy to help if you post a test script that creates your tables (the actual SQL to create the tables, not a summary that is missing nullability, uniqueness, and foreign key relationships), inserts a few rows of dummy data, and shows your desired results vs. the results you are currently getting. At the moment, the question remains confusing to me and you are not doing as much as you could to make it easier to help you.

Comment: @GeoffPatterson here is the [Sql Fiddle Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4751f9/1) . Now, if you execute the query mentioned above, you have a result where the comboid field has the same value in every row, when the result I would like to have is : In the first row,  I would need the value '1', and the second row with the original value of '3' should dissapear and not appear with the value of '1'

Comment: I added an answer based on that fiddle. It might also be possible to further simplify the query, but it's hard to be sure without a more detailed understanding of the data model and problem. In any case, hope this helps you to make progress on your problem.

Comment: @GeoffPatterson I will try with that query and make the modifications to see if it matches my problem. Because there are some sensitive data, I do not know if I can provide more details. If I can, I surely will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query matches your description from *UPDATE 1* (with inline comments showing how it matches) and also yields the correct result for your SQL Fiddle (there is no longer an unwanted row for for the `2015-10-21` sale).

```
-- (1) Check the sales table if it has any combo with duration=0 for the selected user
DECLARE @finalComboId INT = (
    SELECT TOP 1 s.comboid
    FROM sales s
    JOIN combo c
        ON s.comboid = c.id
        AND c.duration = 0
    WHERE s.username = 'user1'
)

IF (@finalComboId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT s.username, s.saledate, r.destinationcombo as comboid
    FROM (
        -- (2) If there is a result, then take the most recent combo
        -- (with duration <> 0 and with most recent saledate)
        SELECT TOP 1 c.id AS recent_comboid
        FROM combo c
        JOIN sales sc
            ON sc.comboid = c.id
            AND sc.username = 'user1'
        WHERE c.duration <> 0
        ORDER BY sc.saledate DESC
    ) rc
    -- Find all sales rows from that most recent combo
    -- (The SQL Fiddle has just one, but more generally I assume there could be multiple)
    JOIN sales s
        ON s.comboid = rc.recent_comboid
    -- (3) After finding that combo, than calculate from relation the destinationcombo...
        -- NOTE: I intrepret this as finding all sales rows from that most recent combo
    JOIN related r
        ON r.finalCombo = 3 --...where FinalCombo is the combo found on step 1)
        AND r.sourceCombo = s.comboid --...and sourcecombo is the combo found on step 2).
END
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM sales WHERE username='user1'
GO
```

However, there are a few things that remain confusing and leave me wondering if I am interpreting the problem correctly:

- The `sourcecombo` field is not used in your example query, but the problem statement indicates that it is important when matching to `relation`.
- Why does the `ELSE` clause select all rows from `sales` when the the main body is selecting only the most recent combo?
- What if there is more than one combo with `duration = 0`? There is no guidance in the problem statement about which row should be picked.

Comment: About your questions: 1) I haven't used the `sourcecombo` in my query,  because even I was not certain how to use it
2) The else statement is put only as e test result, it has no specific  function
3) If there is more than 1 combo with duration=0, this is a more complicated issue, because you would have to search about each of them, if they have a source-combo definer, and research by the above query

Comment: With the right modifications, it worked. Thank you very much :)